# Imagemagick, place a created image over another without saving

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I want to stay away from using exec if possible. I have a jpg image on the server that never changes. I just want to place some text over the top of it but I want that text to be curved and virticle. So far I have created the virticle curved text with a transparent background. Now I just want to slide it over an image that is already made and sitting on the server. Is this possible to do with out saving the generated text image I have?

I have been playing with compositeImage but I am messing something up because the page fails to load with no error.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$phone='555-555-5555';
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFontSize(48);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);
$draw->setFillColor('#'.$color);

$textOnly = new Imagick();
$textOnly->newImage(900, 300, "none");
$textOnly->setImageFormat('png');
$textOnly->annotateImage($draw, 0, 100, 0, $phone);
$distort = array(270);
$textOnly->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);

$textOnly->setImageMatte(true);
$textOnly->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_ARC, $distort, false);
$textOnly->setImagePage(0, 0, 0, 0);

$textOnly->setformat('png');
$textOnly->cropImage(170, 445, 45, 105);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
print $textOnly->getimageblob();
```

I have also tried the above code with this at the end but I get 500 errors:

```
$bgImage->readImage(BASE_PATH.'/src-images/background.jpg');
$bgImage->compositeImage($textOnly, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 10, 20); 
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $bgImage->getimageblob();
```

Here is the resulting image when I get it working with text only and without trying to add the second image:

[image: The resulting image]

Answer (score 0):

This resolved it....

$bgImage = new Imagick

NOT

$bgImage->readImage